# How do I control two listboxes using a Vertical Scrollbar?

Tags: c#, winforms, .net-2.0

I've got a Windows Form that has 6 listboxes in it.

I'm trying to find / make a code that would make them scroll together. So I dropped a Vertical Scroll Bar onto the form, then put in the following code:

```
private void vScrollR_Scroll(object sender, ScrollEventArgs e)
{
    int i = vScrollR.Value;
    lstcr1.SelectedIndex = i;
    lstpr1.SelectedIndex = i;
    lstsr1.SelectedIndex = i;
    lstcr2.SelectedIndex = i;
    lstpr2.SelectedIndex = i;
    lstsr2.SelectedIndex = i;
}
```

For some reason though, it won't work (i always returns 0). Am I going about this the wrong way? Is there any other way to achieve what I want? Perhaps, there's a method I need first?

Many thanks to all who will answer.

Comment: have you thought about creating a delegate that would handle this..?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change SelectedIndex to TopIndex. I just tried this and it works.

To keep the UI in sync while updating, you can use Control.BeginUpdate and Control.EndUpdate

```
        listBox1.BeginUpdate();
        listBox2.BeginUpdate();
        listBox1.TopIndex = 
        listBox2.TopIndex = ++x;
        listBox1.EndUpdate();
        listBox2.EndUpdate();
```

Comment: That worked. Question, though. They do not scroll at the same time, although they do eventually end up on the same item, some of the listboxes are delayed. Any ideas on how to fix this?

Comment: I have updated my answer to address your question about the UI lagging. Please make sure to mark the question as answered if you are happy

Answer (score 1):

Try to Create a Separate Class that Inherits from Listbox.

I hope that this will help you.

```
using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;

public class myScrollingListBox : ListBox 
{
  // Event declaration
  public delegate void myScrollingListBoxDelegate(object Sender, myScrollingListBoxScrollArgs e);
  public event myScrollingListBoxDelegate Scroll;
  // WM_VSCROLL message constants
  private const int WM_VSCROLL = 0x0115;
  private const int SB_THUMBTRACK = 5;
  private const int SB_ENDSCROLL = 8;

  protected override void WndProc(ref Message m) 
  {
    // Trap the WM_VSCROLL message to generate the Scroll event
    base.WndProc(ref m);
    if (m.Msg == WM_VSCROLL)
    {
      int nfy = m.WParam.ToInt32() & 0xFFFF;
      if (Scroll != null && (nfy == SB_THUMBTRACK || nfy == SB_ENDSCROLL))
        Scroll(this, new myScrollingListBoxScrollArgs(this.TopIndex, nfy == SB_THUMBTRACK));
    }
  }
  public class myScrollingListBoxScrollArgs 
  {
    // Scroll event argument
    private int mTop;
    private bool mTracking;
    public myScrollingListBoxScrollArgs(int top, bool tracking)
    {
      mTop = top;
      mTracking = tracking;
    }
    public int Top
    {
      get { return mTop; }
    }
    public bool Tracking
    {
      get { return mTracking; }
    }
  }
}
```